# IEnumerable contains IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I have two `IEnumerable` objects and I want to validate if one of them contains all the elements of the other.

I'm using `obj1.Intersect(obj2).Any()` but the intersection is not working as I'd expect. It returns true even just one of the elements in `obj2` exists in `obj1`.

Is there any way to verify if all the elements of `obj2` exist in `obj1`?

Comment: Use `All` instead of `Intersect.Any`

Comment: If you want them in the same order, you can use `SequenceEqual`. Otherwise, you could check that the intersection has the same length as the subsequence.

Comment: @zerkms `All()` won't work. All what? `Any()` means any items exist, `All()` is meaningless without a lambda.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I did not say they should not pass a predicate. The proper research would involve checking MSDN and the function signature.

Comment: @zerkms exactly. There is no `All()` without a predicate. It wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @Blorgbeard so, what is your point then? It's obvious one must use a predicate.

Comment: My point is that your answer/comment is meaningless without specifying the predicate.

Comment: @Blorgbeard it's a comment, that implies the OP must go and check the documentation. There is no any requirement a SO user is obliged to provide compilable and 100% copy-pasteable comments, sorry.

Comment: Well you may as well have said "use C# code" IMO, given the helpfulness of your original comment.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I may have for sure.

Comment: But whatever, I now understand you didn't mean to say "just replace the word "Any" with "All" in your original code".

Comment: @Blorgbeard SequenceEqual didn't work for me. The items might be in different positions? Thanks though

Comment: Yup, I did say "If you want them in the same order".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no single LINQ method which does what you need without at least specifying a lambda.  There are, however, multiple ways to do it with LINQ.  Here are a few options (to test if `obj2` is a subset of `obj1`):

```
obj1.Intersect(obj2).Count() == obj2.Count()
```

or

```
obj2.All(x=>obj1.Contains(x))
```

or

```
obj2.Except(obj1).Any()
```

Comment: The first one might return false positives if `obj2` has duplicates.

Comment: First option worked! @zerkms you are right... I'll make sure that no duplicates exist.

Comment: What about `.Except()` ? Should do what op expects (3rd example of steven)